# teradata export query using cmd windows not working

Tags: teradata, mload

new post :
i already read tutorial and i found this script

```
.LOGMECH LDAP;
.LOGON  xx.xx.xx.xx/username,password;
.LOGTABLE dbname.LOG_tablename;
DATABASE dbname;
.BEGIN EXPORT SESSIONS 2;
.EXPORT OUTFILE D:\test.txt
MODE RECORD format text;

select a.my_date,b.name2,a.value from dbsource.tablesource a
inner join dbname.ANG_tablename b
on a.name1=b.name2
where value=59000
and a.my_date >= 01/12/2015
;

.END EXPORT;
.LOGOFF;
```

but it is like not working

```
D:\>bteq < dodol.txt
BTEQ 15.00.00.00 Tue Jan 05 14:40:52 2016 PID: 4452

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.LOGMECH LDAP;
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.LOGON  xx.xx.xx.xx/username,

 *** Logon successfully completed.
 *** Teradata Database Release is 13.10.07.12
 *** Teradata Database Version is 13.10.07.12
 *** Transaction Semantics are BTET.
 *** Session Character Set Name is 'ASCII'.

 *** Total elapsed time was 4 seconds.

+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.LOGTABLE dbname.LOG_tablename;
 *** Error: Unrecognized command 'LOGTABLE'.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
DATABASE dbname;

 *** New default database accepted.
 *** Total elapsed time was 2 seconds.


+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.BEGIN EXPORT SESSIONS 2;
 *** Error: Unrecognized command 'BEGIN'.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
.EXPORT OUTFILE D:\test.txt
 *** Warning: No data format given. Assuming REPORT carries over.
 *** Error: Expected FILE or DDNAME keyword, not 'OUTFILE'.
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----
MODE RECORD format text;

MODE RECORD format text;
     $
 *** Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of
 the request and the 'MODE' keyword.
                Statement# 2, Info =6
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.


+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----

select a.my_date,b.name2,a.value from dbsource.tablesource a
inner join dbname.ANG_tablename b
on a.name1=b.name2
where value=59000
and a.my_date >= 01/12/2015
;
```

old post :

I am new in teradata, i have found mload to upload big data, now i have question, is there option to use cmd ( win7 ) to export data from teradata to xxx.txt

```
--- sample
select a.data1,b.data2,a.data3 from room1.REPORT_DAILY a
inner join room1.andaikan_saja b
on a.likeme=b.data2
where revenue=30000
and content_id like '%super%'
and a.trx_date >= 01/12/2015
;
```

this is my mload up.txt

```
.LOGMECH LDAP;
.LOGON xx.xx.xx.xx/username,mypassword;
.LOGTABLE mydatabase.LOG_my_table;
SET QUERY_BAND = 'ApplicationName=TD-Subscriber-RechargeLoad; Version=01.00.00.00;' FOR SESSION;

.BEGIN IMPORT MLOAD
  TABLES mydatabase.my_table
  WORKTABLES mydatabase.WT_my_table
  ERRORTABLES mydatabase.ET_my_table mydatabase.UV_my_table;

.LAYOUT LAYOUT_DATA INDICATORS;
.FIELD number * VARCHAR(20);

.DML LABEL DML_INSERT;
INSERT INTO mydatabase.my_table
(               
number =:number
);

.IMPORT INFILE "D:\folderdata\data.txt"
  LAYOUT LAYOUT_DATA
  FORMAT VARTEXT
  APPLY DML_INSERT;

.END MLOAD;
.LOGOFF &SYSRC;
```

i need solution to export file to my laptop, just like my script that i put ---sample title ....
i use that script from teradasql, and i am search for cmd script

Comment: Your script is for FastExport, but you tried to run it using BTEQ, of course this fails. You might run `fexp < dodo.txt` instead, if FastExport is installed (or switch to a BTEQ export), but: As Rob Paller already wrote, FastLoad/MultiLoad/FastExport are legacy tools, you better learn TPT instead. Download the manuals at info.teradata.com, e.g. locate the correct version of *TPT User Guide* matching your release at www.info.teradata.com/templates/eSrchResults.cfm?&txtpid=B035-2445

Comment: result error : `code` **** 18:18:37 UTY1006 CLI error: 244, MTDP: EM_SSOLOGONFAIL(244): SSO logon
     failed by gateway.
**** 18:18:37 UTY2410 Total processor time used = '0.0936006 Seconds' `code` @dnoeth

perhaps i should use TPT ? since i still use version 13 for database.

Comment: If you get "*** CLI error: MTDP: EM_SSOLOGONFAIL(244): SSO logon failed by gateway." try setting environment variable GUILOGON=NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a few MB and an adhoc export you can use SQL Assistant: Set the delimiter in *Tools-Options-Export/Import*, maybe modify the settings in *Tools-Options-Export* and then click *File-Export Results* before submitting your Select. (Similar in TD Studio)

Otherwise the easiest way to extract data in a readable delimited format is TPT, either `Export` for large amounts of data (GBs) or `SQL Selector` (MBs). TPT is available for most Operating Systems including Windows.

There's a nice User Guide with lots of example scripts:
 [Job Example 12: Extracting Rows and Sending Them in Delimited Format](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2445_035K/2445ch06.100.08.html#ww10985228)

In your case you'll define a *generic template file* like this:

```
DEFINE JOB EXPORT_DELIMITED_FILE
DESCRIPTION 'Export rows from a Teradata table to a delimited file'
(
  APPLY TO OPERATOR ($FILE_WRITER() ATTR (Format = 'DELIMITED'))
  SELECT * FROM OPERATOR ($SELECTOR ATTR (SelectStmt = @ExportSelectStmt)); 
);
```

Change `$SELECTOR` to `$EXPORT` for larger exports.

Then you just need a *job variable file* like this:

```
SourceTdpId         = 'your system'
,SourceUserName     = 'your user'
,SourceUserPassword = 'your password'
,FileWriterFileName = 'xxx.txt'
,ExportSelectStmt   = 'select a.data1,b.data2,a.data3 from room1.REPORT_DAILY a
inner join room1.andaikan_saja b
on a.likeme=b.data2
where revenue=30000
and content_id like ''%super%''
and a.trx_date >= DATE ''2015-12-01'' -- modified this to a valid date literal
;'
```

The only bad part is that you have to double any single quotes within your select, e.g. `'%super%' -> ''%super%''`.

Finally you run a `cmd`:

```
tbuild -f your_template_file -v your_job_var_file
```

Comment: as a @RobPaller +1 recommendation to dnoeth answer. i put my mload script. 

-- i still not understand to create txt file to run like c:\>mload < up.txt
-- by the way, where i can search tutorial to learn this sciprt ... like if i want to import i have already know use mload ....

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the volume of data you wish to extract from Teradata you can use Teradata BTEQ or the Teradata Parallel Transport (TPT) utility with the `EXPORT` operator from the command line to extract the data.

The TPT utility is the eventual replacement for the legacy Teradata Load and Unload utilities (FastLoad, MultiLoad, FastExport, and TPump) and provides an easier mechanism to produce delimited flat files over FastExport. TPT is fairly flexible and effective for exporting large volumes of data to channel or network attached clients.

Teradata BTEQ can perform lightweight load and unload functions. The BTEQ manual is pretty good at providing you an overview of how to use the various commands to produce a semi-structured report or data extract. It doesn't have a simple command to produce a delimited flat file. If you review the manual's overview of the `EXPORT` command you should get a good feel for how BTEQ behaves when working with channel or network attached clients.